# form not uploading with widget_tweaks django

Tags: css, django, forms, widget

im trying to style my form a bit and came across this widget_tweaks. I installed it and now im able to access each form tag and give them css classes and so on but when I try to submit the form its not working. Like the page is just reloading but nothing happens... Do I have to rewrite the view or make some changes in the model? Hope somebody can help me.

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form name="form" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
   <div class="md-form-group float-label">
   {% render_field field class="md-input" %}
    <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value='Create Post' />

</form>
```

When I use the {{form}} everything works except tat I cannot style the tags...

Every comment is welcome.

Comment: Are you posting to the current page? If not, your action url is missing in the from tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works with `{{ form }}` it should also work with widget-tweaks without altering your view code.

Edit:

The correct way to add classes in widget_tweaks is:

```
{% render_field field_name class+="css_class_1 css_class_2" %}
```

Or

```
{{ form.field_name|add_class:"css_class_1 css_class_2" }}
```

And to be complete: you can show the errors by manually adding {{ field.errors }} for the fields you want to display error messages

Comment: no the image is going to another page. I worked with {% load widget_tweaks %}
Title: {{ form.title|add_class:"" }} and now it is working somehow. only thing that is strange now is that I don't get a message like this field is required when I try to upload something it just reloads the page. if I fill in everything correctly than everything works fine... thanks anyway

Comment: Ah yes the classes need to be added with an add_class filter. And the reason you are not getting your error messages is because they need to be added manually when using widget_tweaks. Every field has an errors attribute which you can display: {{ field.errors }}. You can loop over the errors attribute as wel.

Comment: @Petter Friberg: I edited my answer, apparently to add a class using the render_field template tag **class+=""** is needed